# Getting 0 status in ajax request

Tags: ajax, status

I am new to ajax. I have just started learning it. Below is my first ajax script. In tutorial same script shows the status 200 but when I ran it on my browser, the status is 0. Moreover, output is displayed only on firefox, in chrome and in IE, no output is shown

```
window.onload=onload_ajax;
var xhr=false;
function onload_ajax() 
{
if(XMLHttpRequest())
    xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
else if(window.ActiveXObject){
    xhr= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
if(xhr){
    xhr.onreadystatechange=showState;
    xhr.open("GET","colors.xml",true);
    xhr.send(null);
    }
    else document.getElementById('updateArea').innerHTML="Ahh... Some Error..!!";

}

function showState(){

    var curmsg= document.getElementById('updateArea').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('updateArea').innerHTML=curmsg+"<p> The current
     Requestst state is "+ xhr.readyState + " and the status is "+ 
     xhr.status + " . </p>"

    }
```

Output on firefox

```
 The current Request state is 1 and the status is 0 .

The current Request state is 1 and the status is 0 .

The current Request state is 2 and the status is 0 .

The current Request state is 3 and the status is 0 .

The current Request state is 4 and the status is 0 .
```

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your browsers to latest versions, and remove the `()`:

```
if(XMLHttpRequest)
```